# why is my Javascript function not working properly?

Tags: javascript, function

In my function I am trying to figure out the amount of years you would have to save a specified amount of money before you  would have a million dollars.
However my function is console.logging numbers  in the thousands instead of years.

```
//The function I have created.
function retirement(yearsTillPaid){

//Why does it not work right?
return function(millionDollarDream){
    var goalTo = 1000000;
    var baller = goalTo / millionDollarDream;
    var amount = millionDollarDream / baller;
    var howManyYears = goalTo / amount;
    console.log(howManyYears); 
     }
  }


  //calling my function
  var retirementUs = retirement(250,000);
  var retirementNk = retirement(1);
  var retirementAu = retirement(1);
  var retirementGermany = retirement(1);

  retirementUs(250,000);
  retirementNk(140,100);
  retirementAu(333,000);
  retirementGermany(50,000);
```

Comment: `retirement` only accepts one parameter, I'm not sure why you're passing it two in the first call? (and `000` is just `0`)

Comment: I think @krisj is assuming param to be a single value with comma separated (250,000) but this is not how numbers work in javascript. It should be 250000 and not 250,000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both functions expect a single Number as parameter. However they will run without error when given two.

It looks like you want to do a calculation with `250000` instead of `250`.
The added comma results in two parameters: `250` and `0`.